# Resample Image DPI using HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way I can resample an image purely on the client-side that a user uploads?. I'd like to be able to change the DPI and possibly alter the width/height. Can this be achieved purely using HTML/Javascript? I know there are libraries like GD and Image Magick for PHP but I just want to know if it can be done without those,

Thanks!